# Drobo file listing no showing

Tags: nas, file-sharing, drobo

I have a Drobo that has a **ton** of my personal information on it.  I've recently had some issues with it and it had to rebuild its entire structure I believe.  It took about 2 days before it finally stopped blinking.

Now when I open the folder via my Mac it shows that it is empty. So I opened the terminal and did an `ls -la` and it didn't show anything. So just to try I did a `cd` to a directory I knew existed an it worked and I can list all the files.

Can anyone explain to me how to fix the root directory so it will list my files?

Here is a screenshot demonstrating the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this question over the past few days.  I performed a 'fsck_hfs /dev/diskXsX' and it went through fixing the drive a couple times and everything started being listed again.  Hopefully someone else can use this info.  It had nothing to do with the drobo and just the fact that filesystem was messed up.